# Wifi not working in dell xps l502x

Tags: 12.04, wireless, iwlwifi

I am using ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell XPS 15 L502X. Now I cannot seem to install the intel wifi driver. It shows on `lspci`:

[http://i.imgur.com/pX0gI39](https://i.imgur.com/pX0gI39)

However there is no enable/disable wifi option on network options.

[http://i.imgur.com/sSxW87d](https://i.imgur.com/sSxW87d)

Comment: your screenshots are not visible.

Comment: whether wifi icon shown in menu or not

Comment: no it does not show in the menu. and the images can be enlarged from by clicking on it.

Comment: Please show us: sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl Thanks.

Comment: `FATAL: Error inserting iwlwifi (/lib/modules/3.2.0-70-generic/updates/cw-3.6/iwlwifi.ko): Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)`

Answer (score 0):

Stop the network manager

```
    sudo service network-manager stop
```

Remove file on /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state path:

```
    sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
```

Start network manager back:

```
    sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Its still same. No wifi enabling option in the menu. May be I have installed the driver wrong.

Comment: which driver did you installed...

Comment: rfkill unblock all

Comment: i installed iwlwifi from linux backports

Comment: it worked after updating the packages.